# Why don't I see Anaconda libraries in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, anaconda, pydev, miniconda

I'm using Eclipse Javascript 2019-06 and Miniconda3. When I setup the interpreter I don't see any libraries under the packages. I've seen this problem on 2 different windows PC's in completely different environments and can't for the life of me figure out what is going on.

Tried messing around with the paths, uninstall reinstall of both anaconda, miniconda and eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Figures after hours banging my head on this I figured it out 10 mins after posting this. When installing Anaconda or Miniconda there is an option to add it to your environment path. It recommends against this so you have to go against the advice and ignore the scary red text when you select it.